# how to add an element at the begining of a linked list?

Tags: java, linked-list

hello how can I make a `method` that add an element at the beginning of my list.

I know that I have to create a new `Pokeball` here, point new pokeball.next as the head and point the head to the new Pokeball but  I don't know how to do it

My list looks like this right now :

```
Bulbasaur -> Squirtle
```

I want to add `charmander` at the beginning

```
Charmander -> Bulbasaur -> Squirtle
```

When calling the method : `d1.prepend(p3)`, It has to go through Trainer class then `Pokeball` class just like my `addPokemon` method thank you

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pokemon p1 = new Pokemon("Bulbasaur", "grass");
        Pokemon p2 = new Pokemon("Squirtle", "water");
        Pokemon p3 = new Pokemon("Charmander", "fire");
        Trainer d1 = new Trainer("Pierre");
        d1.addPokemon(p1);
        d1.addPokemon(p2);
    }
}

public class Pokemon {
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private int niveau;

    public Pokemon(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.niveau = (int) (Math.random() * (1 * 1 - 100) + 100);
    }
}

public class Trainer {

    public final String name;
    private Pokeball head;

    public Trainer(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addPokemon(Pokemon pok) {
        if (this.head != null) {
            this.head.addPokemon(pok);
        } else {
            this.head = new Pokeball(pok);
        }
    }

    public void prepend(Pokemon pok) {
        this.head.prepend(pok);
    }
}

public class Pokeball {

    private Pokemon pok;
    private Pokeball next;

    public Pokeball(Pokemon pok) {
        this.pok = pok;
    }

    public Pokeball(Pokemon pok, Pokeball next) {
        this.pok = pok;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void addPokemon(Pokemon pok) {
        Pokeball current = this;
        while (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = new Pokeball(pok);
    }

    public void prepend(Pokemon pok) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your list?

Comment: Is your goal to implement your own linked list, without using Collections classes that already exist in the JDK? You should make use of the tools you have available to you in the JDK, unless this is an academic exercise and the goal is to build your own?

Comment: Yes, I have to build my own

Comment: You should state this in your question, otherwise most of the answers you'll get (and rightly so) will be to use the tools you have available in the JDK, rather than re-inventing what already exists

Comment: Yes sorry, i'll remember for the next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call `prepend` on a `Pokeball` to attach something behind it unless each `Pokeball` also holds a reference to the previous `Pokeball`.

The solution is actually much simpler than that. Just make your new `Pokeball` the head of your list:

```
public class Trainer {

        public final String name;
        private Pokeball head;

        ...

        public void prepend(Pokemon pok) {
           Pokeball newPokeball = new Pokeball(pok);
           newPokeball.next = this.head;
           this.head = newPokeball;
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
Another fun exercise is to try to add a pokeball in the middle of a list:
Bulbasaur -> Charmander -> Squirtle

To do this you just need to start from head and go until you find the pokeball that you want to add your new one after. The rest is very similar to above.

```
public void addAfterPokeball(Pokemon theOneToInsertAfter, Pokemon pok) {
           Pokeball newPokeball = new Pokeball(pok);
           Pokeball tmp = head;
           while (tmp != null && tmp.pok.name != theOneToInsertAfter.name) {
               tmp = tmp.next;
           }
           if (tmp!=null){
              newPokeball.next = tmp.next;
              tmp.next = newPokeball;
           } else {
             //could not find the pokeball to insert after
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's Collections classes that will help you here. If you create a LinkedList of Pokemon, this supports addFirst() to insert at the head of the list.

```
List<Pokemon> list = new LinkedList<>();
//other pokemon inserted here 
// ...
//insert new item at front of list   
list.addFirst(newPokemon);
```

Comment: You're right and there is also ArrayDeque to do so. Don't know why you get a downvote without explanation. I updvote your answer.

Comment: The question is about the basics of data structures. this answer doesn't clarify how the insertion actually takes place

Comment: Thanks, I asked the OP if the goal was to impl a linked list without using Collections APIs as an academic exercise and seems the answer is yes. If this is a requirement for the solution then this should be clearly stated in the question, and not voting down answers that don't meet unstated requirements

Answer (score 0):

I try to guess what you want to do. I think you try to implement a chained list of your own.

You need to instantiate a Pokeball and add the current first element of your list as the next element of the instance you just created. I guess your List object contains a reference to your first element, it needs to be changed as well.

Comment: Like this ? In dresseur :  public void prepend(Pokemon pok) {
  this.premiere.prepend(pok);} and in Pokeball : 
 public void prepend(Pokemon pok) {
  Pokeball current = this;
  Pokeball newpok = new Pokeball(pok);
  newpok.next = current;
  current = newpok;}